# Anypointstudio aws EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I took two EC2 instances, both are in same region & security group.

One of the instances, I installed Mulesoft Anypointstudio and deployed few RestAPI's. Using SOAP UI in the same Instance I am able to invoke the API using endpoint as http://localhost:port/getEmployee.

Security Group Inbound Rules:
[image]

[image]
**My requirement is :**

From the Second Instance, I need to invoke the API running in the first Instance.

Using SOAPUI I tried to invoke the API's but I am getting **"Connection Refused"** error.

1. I tried using http://localhost:port/getEmployee.
2. I tried using http://PublicIP of first Instance:port/getEmployee.
3. I tried using http://PublicIP of first Instance/getEmployee

I am able to do PublicIP ping the of First Instance from the second one.

Please share your thoughts, If I am missing anything.

Comment: Are both instances are on the same subnet?
If yes, you can use the private ip address from one to access another.

Comment: Srikanth - Both of them are in the same subnet.  Tried with PrivateIP no luck.  from the command prompt, I am able to ping the IP without Port number.  When I am adding the port to the IP, I am not able to ping

Comment: Thanks. Can you check the outbound rules?

Comment: Srikanth  - Outbound Open for all traffic.  Add Image to the question above.

Comment: Able to resolve the issue.  As I am using EC2 Windows instance.  I need to create a new Firewall rule and open the ports.